# Prevent textbox containing field with null value from taking up space

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a textbox which is displaying the field Address2. If Address2 has a value, then no problem, but if it has no value, then the textbox is blank,  but still takes up space in that portion of the report.

My problem is I don't want to put any blank space if the text box has a blank value for the Address2 field.

Comment: my basic aim is to do not display blank space if control has blank value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click the textbox and select *Format Field*

Select the *Common tab*

Click the *Formula* button next to the *Suppress*

Change the formula to something like

```
IsNull({REPORT;1.Address2}) or {REPORT;1.Address2} = ""
```

Click *Save and Close*

That should about do it.

Comment: hi,thnks for answer. but still it is giving blank space on my report for the Address 2 . 
Any other Idea about the Same ?

Answer (score 1):

Change textbox height to zero and set CanGrow to true ?

Answer (score 0):

Remove your **suppress formula** from textbox and write it to the **detail section** in which you place your textbox.

Answer (score 0):

This will collapse any blank fields, but they must be inside the same text box.

From [this post](http://forums.asp.net/post/2682581.aspx) on the ASP.NET forums:

> 1) Stick your fields into a text object (if you have not already done so)
>
> 2) Right click on the object and select Format Object
>
> 3) Scroll to the bottom and click the checkbox "Supress Embedded Field Blank Lines"

In CR 2013:

[image]

To prevent the text box from taking up extra height with empty space, utilize Charles' answer by shrinking the text box to the minimum size required and checking `CanGrow` in the formatting options.

To handle any labels, for instance if you wanted to display the text **Address 2:** next to the Address2 field, add a formula field `Address2Label` and sets its formula to

```
IF ( ISNULL(Address2) ) THEN
    ""
ELSE
    "Address 2:"
```

then place this in the text box.